# Extract last day of the month from MMM(M)YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-conversion

How can I extract the last day of the month from dates like

DEC2009, APR2013, AUG2008, NOV2017, JUL2014 etc.

I've tried datepart, convert, cast, month, year and I keep getting in a mess with type conversion errors.

Comment: None of those are dates; that's the problem. Dates aren't strings, they are binary values, and have a year, month *and* **day** component. Your strings are missing the latter and likely why your attempts aren't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `try_convert` and `eomonth()`

```
declare @date varchar(7)='jul2014'

select Day(EOMonth(Try_Convert(date, @date)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
SELECT
    dt,
    DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1,
                         CONVERT(datetime, '01' + dt, 106))) AS dt_eom
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The strategy here is to first build from e.g. `DEC2009` the string `01DEC2009`.  Then, we use `CONVERT` with mask 106.  We obtain the final day of the month by adding one month and then subtracting one day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(20)='DEC2009'

SELECT Day(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CAST(DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM, -1, @date),-1) AS 
DATE),100))
```

And

```
SELECT
date,
Day(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CAST(DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM, -1, date),-1) AS 
DATE),100)) AS date_eom
FROM Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EOMONTH` function to get the last day in a month.

First construct an actual date value: add `01` to the beginning, then convert using style `106`. If you just use `CONVERT` or `CAST` without a style parameter, you may run into issues due to local culture. Instead you should specify the style explicitly.

```sql
SELECT
    dt,
    EOMONTH( CONVERT(date, '01' + dt, 106) ) AS dt_eom
FROM yourTable;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=248e4de162a4e0342e5c5d4e742eb5c6)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all (except for Larnu who didn't seem to understand or answer the question)

Your helpful advice and specifically the "TRY_CONVERT" allowed me to work that the two entries where the months were 4 characters fields that were throwing it. My final code was:

```
EOMONTH(CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(TRIM(myField),3) + RIGHT(TRIM(myField),4)))
```

and it worked fine. :)

Happy days!

Comment: Hi Shortmeister, you really should edit your answer and remove the hint about Larnu not answering properly. Larnu's comment is correct and helpfull, although it's not a fully blown solution. SO is not a *please solve my problem* but a *please help me to solve my problem* platform... One important hint about yours: **Language**-dependant dates (like `DEC2009`) are bound to your system's culture. Your working code would break on a German machine, where this was `DEZ2009`). Just to keep this in mind...